# Matrix Inequality Relations for Symmetric Matrices and Positive Semi-Definiteness

Tags: matrices, inequality

**Background Info:**

We know that $ C \preceq D$ if and only if $D - C$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

---

**Question:**

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are two symmetric matrices, and we have $A, B \preceq  \frac{I}{2}$.

Prove that if $ A(I - A) \preceq B(I - B) $,  then we have:
$ A \preceq B $.

---

**My try:**

Initially, using the problem's assumption:
$ A(I - A) \preceq B(I - B) $
which means:
$ B - B^2 - A + A^2 \geq 0 $

Re-arranging the terms, we get:
$ (A - B)(A + B + I) \geq 0 $

Since both $ A $ and $ B $ are matrices less than or equal to $ \frac{I}{2} $, we have:
$ A + B \leq I $
and adding $ I $ to both sides:
$ A + B + I \leq 2I $

This implies that $ A + B + I $ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

On the other hand, $ A - B $
is also a positive semi-definite matrix. Therefore, the conclusion is:
$ A \preceq B $

However, this solution works in a situation where the matrix product of A and B is not sensitive to the interchange of the two matrices.

Comment: Right - nothing guarantees that $AB = BA$.